# how do I process returned Either

Tags: scala, either

if a scala function is

```
def A(): Either[Exception, ArrayBuffer[Int]] = {
...
}
```

what should be the right way to process the returned result?
`val a = A()`
and ?

Comment: You can also use a Try[ArrayBuffer[Int]], this has the Exception part built in. In that case you have to pattern match: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try

Answer (score 50):

I generally prefer using `fold`.  You can use it like map:

```
scala> def a: Either[Exception,String] = Right("On")

a.fold(l => Left(l), r => Right(r.length))
res0: Product with Either[Exception,Int] = Right(2)
```

Or you can use it like a pattern match:

```
scala> a.fold( l => {
     |   println("This was bad")
     | }, r => {
     |   println("Hurray! " + r)
     | })
Hurray! On
```

Or you can use it like `getOrElse` in `Option`:

```
scala> a.fold( l => "Default" , r => r )
res2: String = On
```

Comment: I should mention that if you _only_ want to use it to map the right-hand side, `a.right.map(_.length)` is less typing and does what you want.  Generally, the `.right` and `.left` methods make `Either` work a lot like option, except instead of preserving `None` as the other case like `Option` does, it preserves whatever the opposite side of the `Either` is.  Likewise, `a.right.getOrElse` is simpler than `fold`.  What I like about `fold` is that you can do all of these things at once and combine them.

Comment: The problem with using right.map is that you can't escape into left (e.g. make some Right values into a Left, e.g. if they're an error).

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is with pattern matching

```
val a = A()

a match{
    case Left(exception) => // do something with the exception
    case Right(arrayBuffer) => // do something with the arrayBuffer
}
```

Alternatively, there a variety of fairly straightforward methods on Either, which can be used for the job.  Here's the scaladoc http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Either

Answer (score 4):

One way is

```
val a = A();
for (x <- a.left) {
  println("left: " + x)
}
for (x <- a.right) {
  println("right: " + x)
}
```

Only one of the bodies of the for expressions will actually be evaluated.

Comment: Ok, this works, but in my opinion this is misusing `for` in an ugly way. If you see a `for`, you expect a loop, but here it's used as a kind of `if` statement. Pattern matching (see answer by Dave Griffith) is much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Well it depends. In Scala for expressions have broader semantics than looping. Basically everything which has map/flatmap can be used with for. This is convenient i.e. in the case of Option.