# How should I use MayErr[IntegrityConstraintViolation,Int] in Scala and Anorm?

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework, anorm

I use [Anorm](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/anorm) to do database queries. When I do an `executeUpdate()`, how should I do proper error handling? it has return type `MayErr[IntegrityConstraintViolation,Int]`, is this a Set or a Map?

There is an [example](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/anorm#ExecutingSQLrequests), but I don't understand how I should handle the return value:

```
val result = SQL("delete from City where id = 99").executeUpdate().fold( 
    e => "Oops, there was an error" , 
    c => c + " rows were updated!"
)
```

How do I check if the query failed? (using `result`), and how do I get the numer of affected rows if the query was successful?

At the moment I use this code:

```
SQL(
"""
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname) VALUES ({firstname}, {lastname})
"""
).on("firstname" -> user.firstName, "lastname" -> user.lastName)
    .executeUpdate().fold(
            e => "Oops, therw was an error",
            c => c + " rows were updated!"
)
```

But I don't know how my error-handling code should look like. Is there any example on how to use the return value of type `MayErr[IntegrityConstraintViolation,Int]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obviously do a

```
val updateResult = ....executeUpdate()
val success = updateResult.fold(e => false, c => true)
```

It looks like you can also call

```
val success = updateResult.isRight
```

More generally, you can access the wrapped Either with

```
updateResult.e match {
    case Left(error) => ... do something with error ...
    case Right(updateCount) => ...do something with updateCount...
}
```

Maybe someone more familiar with Play would explain why scala.Either is wrapped in MayErr?

Comment: It's easier to do it as the example shows: `updateResult.fold(error => {/* do something with error */}, updateCount => {do something with updateCount})`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `MayErr` is wrapping `Either`. So it's neither a `Map` nor a `Set`, but rather an object that can contain one of two differently typed objects.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496304/how-do-i-process-returned-either), and you'll see some ways of processing an Either object, which in this case contains either an IntegrityConstraintViolation or an Int. Referring to [http://scala.playframework.org/.../Scala$MayErr.html](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/api/scala-0.9.1/play/utils/Scala$MayErr.html), it looks like you can grab an Either object by referring to the value member `e`. There seems to be an implicit conversion available too, so you can just treat a `MayErr[IntegrityConstraintViolation,Int]` as an `Either[IntegrityConstraintViolation,Int]` without further ceremony.