# How to extract Left or Right easily from Either type in Dart (Dartz)

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, either

I am looking to extract a value easily from a method that return a type `Either<Exception, Object>`.

I am doing some tests but unable to test easily the return of my methods.

**For example:**

```
final Either<ServerException, TokenModel> result = await repository.getToken(...);
```

To test I am able to do that

```
expect(result, equals(Right(tokenModelExpected))); // => OK
```

Now how can I retrieve the result directly?

```
final TokenModel modelRetrieved = Left(result); ==> Not working..
```

I found that I have to cast like that:

```
final TokenModel modelRetrieved = (result as Left).value; ==> But I have some linter complain, that telling me that I shouldn't do as to cast on object...
```

Also I would like to test the exception but it's not working, for example:

```
expect(result, equals(Left(ServerException()))); // => KO
```

So I tried this

```
expect(Left(ServerException()), equals(Left(ServerException()))); // => KO as well, because it says that the instances are different.
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok here the solutions of my problems:

**To extract/retrieve the data**

```
final Either<ServerException, TokenModel> result = await repository.getToken(...);
result.fold(
 (exception) => DoWhatYouWantWithException, 
 (tokenModel) => DoWhatYouWantWithModel
);

//Other way to 'extract' the data
if (result.isRight()) {
  final TokenModel tokenModel = result.getOrElse(null);
}
```

**To test the exception**

```
//You can extract it from below, or test it directly with the type
expect(() => result, throwsA(isInstanceOf<ServerException>()));
```

Comment: How do I yield something from here. Like : (exception) => yield DoWhatYouWantWithException, 
 (tokenModel) => yield DoWhatYouWantWithModel

Comment: you can make 'yield result.fold(failure) => Left(failure), (token){return Right(token)});' @GaneshGhodake

Answer (score 18):

Friends,

just create **dartz_x.dart** like this one.

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

extension EitherX<L, R> on Either<L, R> {
  R asRight() => (this as Right).value; //
  L asLeft() => (this as Left).value;
}
```

And use like that.

```
import 'dartz_x.dart';

void foo(Either<Error, String> either) {
  if (either.isLeft()) {
    final Error error = either.asLeft();
    // some code
  } else {
    final String text = either.asRight();
    // some code
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not type safe. I've seen people using these functions without additional checks on `isLeft` or `isRight`. The utility functions `asRight` and `asLeft` should perform these checks and return optional values. IMHO

Answer (score 4):

Another way to extract the value is simply to convert to `Option`, then to a `dart` nullable:

```
final Either<Exception, String> myEither = Right("value");

final String? myValue = myEither.toOption().toNullable();
```

If you like you can define a simple extension to shortcut this:

```
extension EitherHelpers<L, R> on Either<L, R> {
  R? unwrapRight() {
    return toOption().toNullable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't post a comment... But maybe you could look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496304/how-do-i-process-returned-either). It's not the same language, but looks like it's the same behaviour.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I found a solution with your link. The philosophy is still the same. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the fold method given by Either and map the part you don't want to null, the part you want to itself:

```
extension EitherExtension<L, R> on Either<L, R> {
  R? getRight() => fold<R?>((_) => null, (r) => r);
  L? getLeft() => fold<L?>((l) => l, (_) => null);
}
```

Then just import the file that contains this extension and you can call .getRight() or .getLeft() on Either instances.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**To extract left or right:**

**Left:**

```
print(result.fold((l) => l, (r) => null))
```

**Right:**

```
print(result.fold((l) => null, (r) => r))
```

Answer (score 0):

I return fold result on Either type

```
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, bool>> call(UpdateReceiptParams params) async {
    Either<Failure, ProcurementStore> procurementStore =
        await _getProcurementStore();
    return procurementStore.fold((_) => Left(ServerFailure()),
        (procurementlStore) async {
      List<ReceiptItem> receiptItems =
          _getReceiptItem(params.shipmentStatus, params.quantityAmounts);
      final Receipt receipt = Receiplt(
          procurementStore: procurementStore,
          costCenter: const CostCenter(),
          receiptItems: receiptItems,
          shipmentId: params.shipmentStatus.Id,
          receiptType: params.shipmentStatus.ShipmentType,
          description: params.description,
          operationPeriodId: 0,
          receiptDate: params.date,
          receiptTime: params.time);
      return await shipmentsRepository.updateReceipt(receipt);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it but make sure u use isLeft / isRight first

```
final workflowUnload = await someEither();
 if (workflowUnload.isLeft()) {
  emit(state.copyWith.call(
     status: JobOrderStatus.error,
     failure: (workflowUnload as Left).value,
   ));
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  Future<Either<Failure, FactsBase>> call(Params params) async {
final resulting = await repository.facts();
return resulting.fold(
  (failure) {
    return Left(failure);
  },
  (factsbase) {
    DateTime cfend = sl<EndDateSetting>().finish;        
    List<CashAction> actions = factsbase.transfers.process(facts: factsbase, startDate: repository.today, finishDate: cfend); // process all the transfers in one line using extensions
    actions.addAll(factsbase.transactions.process(facts: factsbase, startDate: repository.today, finishDate: cfend));
    for(var action in actions) action.account.cashActions.add(action); // copy all the CashActions to the Account.
    for(var account in factsbase.accounts) account.process(start: repository.today);
    return Right(factsbase);
  },
);
```

}

Comment: While this code may solve the question, 
[including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)
of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.