# Calling two methods from a Future Either method, both with Future Either return type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these two methods:

```
Future<Either<Failure, WorkEntity>> getWorkEntity({int id})
```

and

```
Future<Either<Failure, WorkEntity>> updateWorkEntity({int id, DateTime executed})
```

They are both tested and work as expected. I then have this third method that combines the two:

```
Future<Either<Failure, WorkEntity>> call(Params params) async {
  final workEntityEither = await repository.getWorkEntity(id: params.id);
  return await workEntityEither.fold((failure) => Left(failure), (workEntity) => repository.updateWorkEntity(id: workEntity.id, executed: DateTime.now()));
}
```

This method does not work, it always return null. I suspect it is because I do not know what to return in the fold methods. How can this be made to work?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature for the `fold` method is as follows:

```
fold<B>(B ifLeft(L l), B ifRight(R r)) → B
```

your `ifLeft` "Left(failure)" is returning an `Either<Failure, WorkEntity>` but `ifRight` "repository.updateWorkEntity(id: workEntity.id, executed: DateTime.now())" is returning a `Future`.

The easiest solution would be, as described here: [How to extract Left or Right easily from Either type in Dart (Dartz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734044/how-to-extract-left-or-right-easily-from-either-type-in-dart-dartz)

```
Future<Either<Failure, WorkEntity>> call(Params params) async {
  final workEntityEither = await repository.getWorkEntity(id: params.id);
  if (workEntityEither.isRight()) {
    // await is not needed here
    return repository.updateWorkEntity(id: workEntityEither.getOrElse(null).id, executed: DateTime.now());
  }
  return Left(workEntityEither);
}
```

Also this might work (also untested):

```
return workEntityEither.fold((failure) async => Left(failure), (workEntity) => repository.updateWorkEntity(id: workEntity.id, executed: DateTime.now()));
```

Since I can not see any benefit in returning an exception I would just throw the exception and catch it with a `try/catch` block.

Comment: In the first, I get "Error: The argument type 'Either<Failure, WorkEntity>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Failure'" from the "return Left(workEntityEither);". The second one liner return null.

Comment: Well actually it is working, was to tired when testing... sorry

Comment: Do you mean the first solution or the second one?