# How to obtain only the right hand side value from dartz?

Tags: flutter, dartz

How to obtain only the right hand side value from dartz?

**the code is**

```
Some(EitherValue)
```

**the output is:**

```
Some(Right("hi"))
```

How to get the value of hi without "Some(Right" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325640/10734372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EitherValue.getOrElse(() => ""); // the function should return the same type of Right hand side
```

Comment: i have another question, please. what is `optionOf` function for ?